# dynamically populate dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am curious to know if it is possible to append a set of values directly into a dictionary without first first of all storing them in a list, like i am doing in the code below. My idea is to omit tempD, tempR and tempA variables.

```
getD = {}
getR = {}
getA = {}
count = -1
for j in range(0, 180, 45):
    count += 1
    getD[count] = {}
    getR[count] = {}
    getA[count] = {}   
    tempD = [] 
    tempR = [] 
    tempA = [] 
    for k in range(len(lA)):        
        if (j <= lA[k] < j + step):
            tempD.append(lD[k])
            tempR.append(lR[k])
            tempA.append(lA[k])
            getD[count] = tempD
            getR[count] = tempR
            getA[count] = tempA
```

Comment: Please describe what the allowed input and expected output is of the above program.

Comment: Yes.  The easiest way to do this is to have a `defaultdict(list)`, but as long as the key has a list value, you can do `d[key].append(value)`

Comment: Why do you initialize `getD[count]` with `{}`? Don't you want a list at this place? Furthermore, you overwrite it anyway, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` so that `getD[count]` will start as a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict   

getD = defaultdict(list)
getR = defaultdict(list)
getA = defaultdict(list) 
count = -1
for j in range(0, 180, 45):
    count += 1
    for k in range(len(lA)):        
        if (j <= lA[k] < j + step):
            getD[count].append(lD[k])
            getR[count].append(lR[k])
            getA[count].append(lA[k])
```

Comment: `getD` should be a `defaultdict`, then `getD[count]` is a list.  Same for the others

Answer (score 0):

Even though this was not exactly your question: In your case it may be beneficial to use list comprehensions:

```
getD = {}
getR = {}
getA = {}
for count, j in enumerate(range(0, 180, 45)):
    aBound = j + step
    getD[count] = [lD[k] for k, a in enumerate(lA) if j <= lD[k] and a < aBound]
    getR[count] = [lR[k] for k, a in enumerate(lA) if j <= lR[k] and a < aBound]
    getA[count] = [a for a in lA if j <= a and a < aBound]
```

This will also enable you to get rid of the temporary arrays and could also be more efficient.